# Video chat (webRTC) with Chrome to Chrome doesn't work

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, websocket, webrtc, stun

I try to build a simple video chat between two peers. This is the structure :

- Web server : Apache. it's in a LAN. The pc (windows 7) has public ip.
- Signal server: In a VM (VirtualBox Centos 6) on the same pc.
- Client A : Laptop, Vista. I use a Samsung mobile and usb tethering to
  get (external) internet.
- Client B :Laptop, windows 10. I
  use a Samsung tablet and usb tethering to get (external) internet.

I use Mozilla "45.0.1" and Chrome "49.0.2623.112 m"

I use the code from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Signaling_and_video_calling for signal server and clients with some changes

- When i use two Firefox clients (https/wss, self-signed certificate) everything is ok.
- When I use one Chrome client in the LAN (localhost or local ip, https/wss) and another Chrome client (https/wss) with "external" internet (usb tethering) everything is ok.
- When I use two Chrome clients withe "external" internet I don't have ICE connection.
  These are the messages I get in the console

---

- [1:58:58 PM] Call recipient has accepted our call
- webrtc.js:36 [1:58:58 PM] *** WebRTC signaling state changed to: stable
- webrtc.js:36 [1:58:58 PM] *** ICE connection state changed to checking
- webrtc.js:36 [1:58:58 PM] *** Stream added
- webrtc.js:36 [1:58:58 PM] *******************
- webrtc.js:36 [1:58:58 PM] Message received:
- webrtc.js:91 Object
- webrtc.js:36 [1:58:58 PM] Adding received ICE candidate: {"candidate":"candidate:0 1 UDP 2122187007 ---.---.--.--- 63215 typ host","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}
- webrtc.js:36 [1:58:58 PM] Message received:
- webrtc.js:91 Object
- webrtc.js:36 [1:58:58 PM] Adding received ICE candidate: {"candidate":"candidate:4 1 UDP 2122252543 ----:-:----:----:---:----:----:---- 63216 typ host","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}
- webrtc.js:36 [1:58:58 PM] Message received:
- webrtc.js:91 Object
- webrtc.js:36 [1:58:58 PM] Adding received ICE candidate: {"candidate":"candidate:1 1 UDP 1685987327 --.--.--.--- 53499 typ srflx raddr -----.---.--.--- rport 63215","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0}
  3webrtc.js:484
- ******* the candidate is successfully passed to the ICE agent
- webrtc.js:36 [1:59:14 PM] *** ICE connection state changed to failed
- webrtc.js:36 [1:59:14 PM] Closing the call
- webrtc.js:36 [1:59:14 PM] --> Closing the peer connection

---

I use public STUN/TURN server :

```
var STUN = {
    urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302',
};
var TURN = {
    urls: 'turn:64.233.184.127:19305',
    credential: ***
    username: ***
};
```

I don't think it's a problem with the code (client or signal server) since it works with Firefox to Firefox and "local Chrome" to "external" Chrome.

**EDIT** :

Today, I used the code I found from easyRTC.

- Client : ...demos/demo_audio_video_simple.html
- Server : ...server_example/server.js

I had the same results :

- Firefox-Firefox -->OK,
- local Chrome - external Chrome -->OK
- external Chrome - external Chrome --> Failed

I made some small changes to the server for https and port(6503):
(note : I've created a port forward 6502->6503)

```
// Load required modules
var http    = require("https");              // http server core module
var express = require("express");           // web framework external module
var io      = require("socket.io");         // web socket external module
var easyrtc = require("../");           // EasyRTC external module
var fs = require('fs')

// Setup and configure Express http server. Expect a subfolder called "static" to be the web root.
var httpApp = express();
httpApp.use(express.static(__dirname + "/static/"));

// Start Express http server on port 6503
//var webServer = http.createServer(httpApp).listen(6503);

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.crt')
};

// Our HTTP server does nothing but service WebSocket
// connections, so every request just returns 404. Real Web
// requests are handled by the main server on the box. If you
// want to, you can return real HTML here and serve Web content.
var webServer = http.createServer(options, httpApp).listen(6503);
```

The messages of the server :

---

debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Room [default] Running func 'connectionRoomObj.emitRoomDataDelta'
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Room [default] Running func 'connectionRoomObj.generateRoomDataDelta'
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [roomData]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [offer]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [offer]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] EasyRTC message received of type [easyrtc_streamReceived]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcMsg' with msgType [easyrtc_streamReceived]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] EasyRTC command received with msgType [answer]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [answer]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] EasyRTC command received with msgType [setUserCfg]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] WebRTC setUserCfg command received. This feature is not yet complete.
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcCmd' with msgType [candidate]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC message received of type [easyrtc_streamReceived]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] EasyRTC command received with msgType [setUserCfg]
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][LHX9gZKB__gYlPeUo_gW] WebRTC setUserCfg command received. This feature is not yet complete.
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][9dl9HdL-TPqwCMTeo_gX] Running func 'onEmitEasyrtcMsg' with msgType [easyrtc_streamReceived]

---

So, I proved that the code is not the problem. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem was that the public TURN server I used, changes the username/password every x minutes. I haven't noticed this, so I used the same username/password. When I changed username/password then everything worked fine for Firefox, Chrome, Opera and combinations of them.